# changing colors of google bar chart and convert data into percentage

Tags: javascript, charts

While using google bar chart how to change color of individual bar , and how to convert the data values into percentage.
You can preview it on **http://jsfiddle.net/u4Lwwx1k/**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"></div>

 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales'],
          ['2004',  1000],
          ['2005',  1170],
          ['2006',  660],
          ['2007',  1030, ]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the colours you need to change your first line of the array:

Change  ['Year', 'Sales'],
To:  ['Year', 'Sales', { role: 'style' }],

then each value add the colour to the end like:
 ['2004',  1000,  'blue'],
 ['2005',  1170, '#cccccc'],

I think you will have to program the percentage yourself. Im looking to do the same and cant find any examples.